# My program shows Out Of Memory Error : java heap space

Tags: java

I've written a program in Java that stores a list of pictures, similar to Gallery in smart Phones and i end up with `OutOfMemoryError : java heap space.`

here is my code where i get an `OutOfMemoryError`...

```
public void showImages(){
     // imageList is an array of path of pictures

     for(int i=0; i<imageList.length; i++){
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imageList[i]);
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setIcon(icon);
        panel.add(label); //problem is here

        // I have made a JFrame and added a JPanel which has GridLayout
        // MY Problem Is..
        // When i try to add images in the panel,
        // then my program show 'Out Of Memory Error : java head space'
        // for each and every picture
     }
}
```

Comment: How many images are in imageList?

Comment: What are the size of images? How many images are you loading?

Comment: How much ram do you have?

Comment: It depends on user that how many pictures he select from JFileChooser

Comment: It is not only ram because the JVM paramter define the memory that the program will have.. It is very hard to say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heap is holding the object.. So that means your heap is full with objects

The list is to long so you can do 2 things:

1. Increase the heap space, sometimes it just to small but this is just something to increase the default.. You can't always use it

   Here a simple link that show example: http://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/eclipse-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space/
2. You can make something that will be more smart, You can do something like lazy loading... No need to load tons of data at once.. make it like paging, And every page will get his data.

For example: you have 1000 imagesIcons. So you create only 100(0-100).. When the user press next you show him the next screen with another 100(100-200) etc.. This is how you should handle it..

But still change the heap space to be higher.. The default is too low

Hope that helps

Comment: even when try load 6 to 7 pictures,it shows but with OutOfMemoryError

Comment: Maybe you need to create and cache thumbnails of images instead of holding the entire image in memory.  How large is each image in MB?

Comment: Maybe the heap is already full with something else.. Maybe you still save another big list or objects? This situation need to be with a lot of objects that save in software, Increasing the default heap didn't help?

Comment: My pictures are less than 1 MB

Answer (score 0):

Use [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) to discover how many instances (how many ImageIcons, how many JLabels, etc.) are in memory.  Once you know which instances are in memory (and how much memory each consumes) you can know the cause of your problem.